# Automatic Update TextView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-contentprovider, textview

I have an activity with a textview that shows different quotes every time the previous or backward button is pressed. It'd be really funny if I add 10000 quotes in the arrays.xml file and then pass it through to the textview.

Is there any method using which I can, extract text from my own blog and show quote sin the text view. what I mean is, I don't have to prompt the users to update the entire application and just do an update on the cloud and it gets updated in the app every time the user connects to the app.

Comment: And how do you decide which of the 10000 quotes to show in the `TextView`? Should that be random?

Comment: Hardly Matters. They can be Random. That depends on the Java code,really. Tell me how can I change it dynamically. What I want is it automatically get's contents from my blog and updates the textview.

Comment: It's hard to answer as I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. By your _blog_, do you mean a hierarchy of websites where you publish articles, so the phone would have to parse it? Or would there be for example a text file somewhere on the _blog_ with only the quotes in it?

Comment: Mixed. I'll post quotes on the my blog and the phone would have to parse it. efficiently.

Comment: I think you'll have to implement some kind of logic on the server-side which would give the device new quotes that it doesn't have locally stored. Some kind of a versioning system. Parsing a whole blog of 10000 quotes every time the app starts is not a good idea as it would take lots of time and bandwidth.

Comment: Any idea or example as to how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with server-side development. I have some ideas concerning how it could work, but I am sure you can come up with them too. For example a system that when you add new quotes to the blog, it increments the version number. And then the app can compare its version to the version on the server and if they don't match, download missing quotes. I have no idea how to implement that, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try parsing your xml feed and show that contents into the textview. You can also use a text file and show contents of it using different indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) service to see if this can help you?  I've never looked at it, just thought I'd read somewhere about other developers that have!

Comment: I guess It's all about notifying users that there's an update on the go. The users would still have to go to the play store and update the  application.